# Error 596 when firing Journey Builder API Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Writing PHP code for Salesforce Marketing cloud.
Below are the steps I followed:

- Created an API Event.
- Created a journey using above event.

Generated access token using /v2/token

Then using below code to fire an API Event.

```
$url = 'https://<MY-SUBDOMAIN-URL>/interaction/v1/events';

$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token;
$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json", $authorization);

$data = array(
      'ContactKey' => 'manishkrag@yahoo.co.in',
      'EventDefinitionKey' => <provided correct key>,
      'EstablishContactKey' => true,
      'Data' => array(
                  'Email' => 'manishkrag@yahoo.co.in',
                  'Name' => 'Manish Kumar',
                )
    );

$data = json_encode( $data );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Getting "596 Service Not Found" error message as response.

Can anyone help me to figure our what I am doing wrong.

Thanks all

Comment: Have you verified the client ID and client secret match the MID of your journey?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes all client ID and client secret are fine. Able to solve my issue. I was using wrong post url. It should be subdomain.rest.